# Preposition 'in' or 'at' regarding -front side

Tags: prepositions

if there is '-side' after front, what is correct?
In the front side OR
At the front side

As we all know, we usually use 'in front of' BUT, if there is '-side' thereafter, what now then?

Thx.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I would have thought that 'front' never needs the word 'side' added to it, myself.

Comment: There is also a usage such as 'On the right hand side'. Now I wonder the answer as well !

Comment: In the phrase "front side", the base noun is "side", not "front", and that is what the preposition refers to.  ([the] front is a volume, whereas a side is an area, and "in" implies penetration for 2D objects)

Comment: Neither is correct, nor close to it. Whether you're looking at British or US American or some other variety of English, please take that question to English Language Learners.

Comment: Examples are helpful for these kinds of questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinction between "in" and "at" is one that has been valid even in older forms of English, as you can see in here: 
https://www.etymonline.com/word/at
https://www.etymonline.com/word/in

Normally, "at" is preferred for "nearby, not actually inside" (but can also mean that you are inside the place) while "in" almost always conveys the meaning of being actually inside.
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-in-and-at-How-would-you-explain-the-difference-between-these-two-prepositions-to-a-kid

Thus, you most likely are not "in the frontside", you are "at the frontside".

Edited to take into account an observation made in the comments.

Comment: I don't agree with saying that the (current) meaning of a  word is established by its etymology. This is called the etymological fallacy.

Comment: You are right. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Ok got it. Thx very much

Comment: You are welcome! @Johnnarvin, if you think that this is the best answer you can get, would you care to accept it?

Comment: Also, just throwing up all the ins and ats will not include all the buts.